# How do I determine the difference between values in database column and return the smallest difference?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a column of `DATETIME` values in MySQL and I'm looking to return the smallest difference between any two of those values in the column; I don't need to know what values the difference was between or when it was, just the difference between these two values alone.

My table looks similar to this.

```
id    | launch_date_time
----------------------------
1     | 2012-01-02 18:42:00
2     | 2012-04-05 07:23:50
 ...
x     | 2014-08-07 22:19:11
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the correct direction for constructing such a query?

Comment: Cant you do it on your front-end? like php,python,...?

Comment: I could, using PHP. What would be the best way to do so... foreach loop?

Comment: I think that it'll be difficult to do it with a query (but you can use a DB function). If it's a small data-set I would export it to excel, sort it and use a formula to calculate the differences and sort them - 5 mins work. If it's a big data-set and you'll need to do it on a regular basis, better create a trigger upon INSERT that calculates the  difference between now() and the last INSERT - and save it into a "diff-table".

Answer (score 1):

My first idea is, if your table name is `table` do this

```
select min( abs( datediff(t1.launch_date_time, t2.launch_date_time) ) )
  from table t1
     , table t2
 where t1.id <> t2.id
```

it depends how big those tables are, the above is O(N^2) solution, in O(N * log N) you can do this by sorting and result is min of consecutive elements

```
// pseudo code
list = fromDb();
sort(list);
min = list[1] - list[0];
for i in 2 to list.size()
    min = min( min, list[i] - list[i-1] )
```

Comment: If records are equally ordered by 'id' as well as by 'launch_date_time', and there are no holes in 'id's, then it may be enough to self-join on t1.id = t2.id+1, which has O(n) complexity.

Comment: Correct, but only OP knows if that holds... I'm not quite sure if this is O(n), it depends on internal implementation. For simple for each id find id+1 in log(n) - indexed, it's still O(N * log N), if the index is tree, still can be implemented as tree traversal...

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,FROM_UNIXTIME(launch_date_time) as uTime,max(FROM_UNIXTIME(launch_date_time)) as max from table;

 //do db stuff
  //set the lowest to highest possible number so first comparison it will become the lowest.

   $lowest = $result['max'];

// iterate through array to get each time
foreach ($result['uTime'] as $v)
{

 //iterate again to compare each time u got from first loop to each in this loop

   foreach ($result['uTime as $x)
   { 
 //subtract your first value from the current
        $diff = $v - $x;

 //if its lower then any previous, and its positive set the new lowest.
        if ($diff < $lowest and $diff > 0)
        {
           $lowest = $diff;
        }
   }
}
 echo $lowest;
```

havent tested this....

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  t1.launch_date_time, MIN(t2.launch_date_time) launch_date_time2
FROM launch t1
  JOIN launch t2
    ON t2.launch_date_time > t1.launch_date_time
GROUP BY
  t1.launch_date_time
ORDER BY
  DATE(MIN(t2.launch_date_time)) * 86400 + TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(MIN(t2.launch_date_time))) - DATE(t1.launch_date_time) * 86400 + TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(t1.launch_date_time))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the performance of this query... Join on `launch_date_time`? You do not need `abs`, simply substract t2 time from t1 time, when there is `t2.launch_date_time > t1.launch_date_time` in join...

Comment: INDEX(launch_date_time) will help to optimize joining tables. ABS - I changed the query.

Answer (score 0):

SQL method of doing it in a single statement (difference here in days):-

```
SELECT MIN(DATEDIFF(Sub1.launch_date_time, Sub2.launch_date_time))
FROM
(
    SELECT id, launch_date_time, @aCnt1 := @aCnt1 + 1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM SomeTable
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @aCnt1:=0
    ) Deriv1
    ORDER BY launch_date_time
) Sub1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, launch_date_time, @aCnt2 := @aCnt2 + 1 AS SeqCnt
    FROM SomeTable
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT @aCnt2:=1
    ) Deriv2
    ORDER BY launch_date_time
) Sub2
ON Sub1.SeqCnt = Sub2.SeqCnt
```

SQL Fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc399/1